# Javascript troubles extracting text from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, text, extract

I've made this to try to extract text.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function extractText(node){
    var all = "";
    for (node=node.firstChild;node;node=node.nextSibling){
        alert(node.nodeValue + " = " + node.nodeType);
        if (node.nodeType == 3){
            all += node.nodeValue   
        }
    }
    alert(all);
}
</script>
```

That is located in the head of an html document.
The body looks as such...

```
<body onload = "extractText(document.body)">
Stuff
<b>text</b>
<script>
var x = 1;
</script>
</body>
```

The problem is that the `alert(all);` only shows **"Stuff"**, and it adds a bunch of null things that I don't really understand when doing the `alert(node.nodeValue + " = " + node.nodeType);`. It says null = 3 a few times. Could anyone tell me why this isn't working properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the text from the document, you may want to look in to a recursive call. However, if you don't care about children, remove the first `if (node.hasChildNodes()){}` condition in the following:

```
function extractText(node){
    var txt = '';
    // recursive exploration and option to uncomment the check for a <script>
    // <script>s will have children as the the actual portion being executed
    // is considered a text node (nodeType===3)
    if (node.hasChildNodes()/* && node.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT'*/){
        for (var c = 0; c < node.childNodes.length; c++){
            txt += extractText(node.childNodes[c]);
        }
    }else if(node.nodeType===3){
        txt += node.textContent;
    }
    return txt;
}
alert(extractText(document.body));
```

Also, you probably want to grab [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) over `nodeValue` but that's your call. You can also get more granular and test if the [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeName) is a `SCRIPT` and ignore if (if you so chose) but I'll let you make that determination.

Follow-Up: here's a fiddle you can play with, with the `<script>` test commented and optional whitespace removal: http://jsfiddle.net/KZuk5/2/

Comment: Hmm it still seems to grab the var x =1;

Comment: @OstapHnatyuk: Look at the jsfiddle I posted and uncomment the `nodeName=='script'` portion. Also, if you don't care about the whitespace (like new lines) see [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8XRe/2/).

Comment: OH it was commented out, haha I didn't notice that. It works perfectly, thanks for the help. That helped me understand quite a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of nodes - specifically we're looking at two, a text node and an HTML node. A text node is an object and has a property called `nodeValue` (that you're accessing properly). However, HTML nodes do not have the `nodeValue` property (or rather, it is set to `null`).

To get the inner value of an HTML node use `.innerHTML`.